# Unable to capture overlay sticker in HMS-Core-Face2D-Sticker (HUAWEI) project with function mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback)

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback)
returning image without overlay stickers, can anyone suggest how i can capture image with over lay stickers, the project is **HUAWEI** based **HMS-Core-Face2D-Sticker**. this project like snapchat camera etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the MLFaceGraphic class in the sample code and the following code.

```
        //Image Code
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawCircle(30,50,25,paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(80,20,160,80, paint);
        Rect rect=new Rect();
        rect.set(180, 20, 200, 80);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        canvas.drawText("text", 10, 110, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(10, 120, 300, 120, paint);
        RectF oval=new RectF();
        oval.set(10.0f, 140.0f, 110.0f, 200.0f);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
        oval.set(150.0f, 140.0f, 110.0f, 200.0f);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 150.0f, 140.0f, true, paint);
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.logo));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200,paint);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText("Height："+bitmap.getHeight()+", Width："+bitmap.getWidth(),
                10, bitmap.getHeight()+20, paint);
```

This is a document link：https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Examples/sample-code-0000001050265470

Answer (score 0):

The sample project that you're referring to demo what not design to take picture. Hence, the method

```
 public void takePicture(Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback) {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
    }
```

was never called

To take a picture with sticker on here is a suggestion:

take a look at this [code sample](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201333611965550036?fid=0101187876626530001)

wait until the onDrawFrame

```
@Override
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
```

finish

check to see if the

**Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback**

return an actual image
before calling takePicture method

**public void takePicture(Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback)takePicture()**

This suggestion is base on the code sample above